# Why does apt-cache search find packages which do not match the given regular expression?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, apt

I ran the following command at linux bash:

```
apt-cache search 'hex.*(view|edit)'
```

My intention was to find any software packages whose name/description contains the pattern 'hex.*(view|edit)'. But among the results I got this:

```
kipi-plugins - image manipulation/handling plugins for KIPI aware programs
```

How could this be in the results list? I didn't see any matching string in this result. Is this a bug of the `apt-cache search` command? Or do I mis-understand how the regular expression is used by this command?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but you should always escape or quote shell metacharacters if you don't want them to be expanded by the shell. Better `apt-cache search 'hex.*(view|edit)'`

Comment: Thanks leonbloy. But after I add the single quote, the kipi-plubins is still in the result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`search` does a full text search on all text in a package description, not just the name.  If you want names only, you can use `--names-only`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How could I see the full description of a package? Is it with apt-cache show pkg_name?

Comment: @smwikipedia Thats correct. `apt-cache show <package>` should show the full description.